# IntelliJ won't find generated code from Lombok while gradle does

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.2 installed with the latest Lombok plugin (0.25).
Furthermore, Lombok is enabled for my project (Preferences --> Other Settings --> Lombok Plugin) and the plugin installed.
Annotation Processing is also enabled.
My project uses Java11.

Everything works fine when I run my application via Gradle or run unit tests via ./gradlew test.

When I now configure to use IntelliJ IDEA tooling (Preferences --> Build, Executions, Deployment --> Built Tools --> Gradle --> Both 'Build an Run using:' and 'Run tests using:' set to 'IntelliJ IDEA') it stops working, my generated classes are not found.

I receive exceptions, that my constructors are not found, while they were found when I am using gradle

`(no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)`

Comment: Check if the annotation processor uses the same directory for the generated source files as gradle does.
Does Intellij recognize that folder as source code folder?

Comment: i've heard some problems with using lombok in test classes. Is that the problem here as well?

Comment: I think this is IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.2 regression, it was working in the previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

I've clicked on `Refactor->Lombok->@Log and friends` and IDEA started to compile the code.

Comment: This is a workaround solution for the original question